# How should I get the forecasted values in R using Arima Model?

Tags: r, statistics, analytics, forecasting, arima

I am new to R so doesn't know how exactly the forecasting works in R using Arima Model. I have a dataset is like:
92  Aug-17  9533
93  Sep-17  8718
94  Oct-17  2035
95  Nov-17  2539
96  Dec-17  1333
97  Jan-18  2444
98  Feb-18  9371
99  Mar-18  9697
100 Apr-18  3989
101 May-18  4061
102 Jun-18  2797
103 Jul-18  2949

I want see the forecasted values for next 12  months by using arima model in R. So how should I achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.
[this is a dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMd2K.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Suppose you have fitted your ARIMA model in `fit`

so you can use the following method for predicting values. Here `n` is the number of values you want to predict. In your case, `n` will be 12.

```
pred = predict(fit,n.ahead = 1*n)
```

If you are taking log of values during ARIMA modeling so you use the following method for actual output.

```
values = 2.718^pred$pred
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.Can we have output like next 12 dates along with the predicated values??

Comment: This is my code: -
for1 <- tail(data1,12)
for2 = ts(for1)
arima_fit = auto.arima(for2[,2])
pred <- predict(arima_fit, n.ahead = 1*12)
pred
Do I need to add something more into this?
O/p I am getting is:-
$pred
Time Series:
Start = 13 
End = 24 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 5074.479 4994.452 4994.452 4994.452 4994.452 4994.452 4994.452 4994.452
 [9] 4994.452 4994.452 4994.452 4994.452

$se
Time Series:
Start = 13 
End = 24 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] 2751.131 3476.465 3476.465 3476.465 3476.465 3476.465 3476.465 3476.465
 [9] 3476.465 3476.465 3476.465 3476.465

Comment: you can generate a date and then paste the predicted value with it. else you can save the predicted value as CSV file and generate date very simply in ms excel.

Comment: Ok... So this is the only option we have?And I hope my code is right?

Comment: Thank you @girijesh for helping

Comment: @AbhijitKaware. Please accept this answer by accepting it. If you think it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forecast` package in `R` to forecast. However, your question is very broad, an example would be:

```
library(forecast)

data("airmiles")

auto.arima(airmiles, stepwise = F,approximation = F)->arima_fit # fit an arima model with autoarima 

forecast(arima_fit, h= 12 )->fc # forcast next 12 months 

accuracy(fc) #check accuracy of your forecast
```

for more details [check this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07G6NRC3M)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(forecast)
forecast_horizon <- 12 # because you said 12 months
model <- auto.arima(data)
forecasts <- forecast(model, forecast_horizon)
y_pred <- forecasts$mean
```